# How is Jesus appearing before God in Hebrews 9:24 different from the sons of God presenting themselves before God in Job 1:6?

Tags: hebrews, job

Job 1:6 ASV Now it came to pass on the day when the sons of God came to present themselves before Jehovah, that Satan also came among them

Hebrews 9:24 ASV For Christ entered not into a holy place made with hands, like in pattern to the true; but into heaven itself, now to appear before the face of God for us

Answer (score 6):

There are a large number of differences between the "sons of God" before the throne of God and "Jesus" before the throne of God.  Here are a few:

1. **Jesus is our High Priest** - the sons of God are not.

- Heb 9:11 - But when Christ came as high priest of the good things that have come, He went through the greater and more perfect tabernacle that is not made by hands and is not a part of this creation.  See also Heb 3:1, 4:14, 8:1, etc.

2. **Jesus Sits on the same Throne as with God because Jesus is the King**; the sons of God do not and are not.

- Heb 1:3 - After He had provided purification for sins, He sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high.
- Rev 3:21 - ...  I also overcame and sat down with My Father on His throne.
- Rev 22:3 - And there will not be any curse any longer. And the throne of God and of the Lamb will be in it, and His servants will serve Him.  See also Rev 5.
- John 1:49 - Nathanael answered Him, "Rabbi, You are the Son of God; You are King of Israel."  See also John 12:13, Luke 1:32-34.

3. **The Sons of God appear before the throne to be judged**, Jesus does not because He occupies God's throne.

- 2 Cor 5:10 - For we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ, that each one may receive his due for the things done in the body, whether good or bad.
- Rom 14:10 - Why, then, do you judge your brother? Or why do you belittle your brother? For we will all stand before God’s judgment seat.

4. **Jesus is our mediator, advocate and intercessor before God**, the sons of God are not.

- 1 John 2:1 - My little children, I am writing these things to you so that you will not sin. But if anyone does sin, we have an **advocate** before the Father—Jesus Christ, the Righteous One.
- 1 Tim 2:5 - For there is one God and one **mediator** between God and men, the man Christ Jesus See also Heb 8:6, 9:15, 12:25.
- Rom 8:34 - Who is there to condemn us? For Christ Jesus, who died, and more than that was raised to life, is at the right hand of God—and He is **interceding** for us. See also Heb 7:25.

5. **Jesus is perfect and does not need salvation** - unlike the Sons of God.

- Heb 7:25 - Such a high priest truly befits us—One who is holy, innocent, undefiled, set apart from sinners, and exalted above the heavens.

6. **Jesus is on God's throne to accept praise and worship**.  The Sons of God do not

- Phil 2:9-11 - Therefore God exalted Him to the highest place and gave Him the name above all names, that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, in heaven and on earth and under the earth, and every tongue confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.  See also Rev 5:8-14.

Lastly, Satan presenting himself among the "Sons of God" in Job 1 & 2 is for a meeting whose function and purposes are not stated.  However, Satan is not and never was a "son of God".

Comment: Up-voted +1 on several counts.

Comment: @Dottard, fine response overall. Where do you get the idea in point 5 that the Job sons of God need salvation? You seem to conflate the Christian sons of God with the Job sons of God... who where present at the foundation of the Earth (Job  38:4-7), based on your uses of Christian passage in point 3.

Comment: @Austin - for the most part, "sons of God" refers to humans as in Gen 6:2, 4, Deut 32:8, Ps 29:1, 89:6, etc.  It is only in Job 1:6, 2:1 where it might be something else.

Comment: @Dottard. The verses cited does not speak of thrones but since you mentioned the throne of God and the throne of Jesus,did Jesus appear to his God as the verse say? With point #2 on your answer. Will those who conquer  sit  and share the same throne that Jesus now sits?  Revelation 3:21? Who is the source of Jesus' throne?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - then what of Heb 8:1, 12;2, Rev 5:13, etc.  Apparently, all have thrones in heaven, and Jesus sits on the Father's throne but still has His own throne according to Rev 3:21.  See also Rev 20:4-6.  In any case, what is your point of objection this time?  Could you be more specific rather than just objectioning?

Comment: @Dottard. If as your answer says the "sons of God" before the throne of God" and "Jesus Sits on the same Throne as with God because Jesus is the King;" did the sons of God appear to Jesus or God? Did Jesus appeared to God or did he appeared to himself?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - do you take pleasure in deliberately being difficult?  Jesus appears before the throne of God and takes the same throne.  See Rev 5.  All other sons of God appear before the throne of God, on which Jesus also sits, for various reasons as stated above.

Comment: @Dottard. So if as stated on your comment "All other sons of God appear before the throne of God, on which Jesus also sits, for various reasons as stated above" Was Jesus sitting on God's throne when the sons of God appeared before the throne of God?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - we are not told.

Answer (score 6):

Just an addition to Dottard's fine answer.

> Neither by the blood of goats and calves, but by his own blood he entered in once into the holy place, having obtained eternal redemption for us. - Hebrews 9:12

Jesus entered the Most Holy place by virtue of his own blood.  It was not by invitation nor by the merit of anyone or anything else.  No one else could have done such a thing. Additionally, there are at least two monumental things that Jesus accomplished in that entry that the other "sons of God" did not and could not.

He obtained eternal salvation for us by putting away sin:

> For Christ is not entered into the holy places made with hands, which are the figures of the true; but into heaven itself, now to appear in the presence of God for us: Nor yet that he should offer himself often, as the high priest entereth into the holy place every year with blood of others; For then must he often have suffered since the foundation of the world: but now once in the end of the world hath he appeared to **put away sin by the sacrifice of himself**. - Hebrews 9:24-26

He purified the heavenly things with his own blood:

> It was therefore necessary that the patterns of things in the heavens should be purified with these; but the heavenly things themselves with better sacrifices than these. - Hebrews 9:23

The very one by whom the "sons of God" were created certainly returns back into the center point of Heaven by a different and grander entrance than any other:

> And I beheld, and, lo, in the midst of the throne and of the four beasts, and in the midst of the elders, stood a Lamb as it had been slain, having seven horns and seven eyes, which are the seven Spirits of God sent forth into all the earth. - Revelation 5:6

Comment: This is also a good answer and an excellent addition to mine.  +1.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It is ***a category error*** to lump all "sons of God" with THE Son of God, who is "the only-begotten Son".

The many "sons of God" are all creatures created by the Creator.

The only-begotten Son of God - John 1:18 -  is their Creator.

That is shown in John 1:1-14. This only-begotten Son of God "made everything that was made". The angelic "sons of God" were all created - by the Word of God who became flesh as Jesus of Nazareth, and who is also identified in that chapter as the Son of God.

Further, there is ***another category error*** made by confusing location with relationship.

The many sons of God had to locate themselves before the throne of God in heaven (as in Job 1:6). THE Son of God has that title of "the only-begotten Son" to show his unique relationship with the Father. That is shown in John 1:18 -

> "No man hath seen God at any time: the only begotten Son, which is in
> the bosom of the Father, he hath declared him." (A.V.)

The only begotten Son is the eternal, uncreated Son, so that after he lowered himself to become the man Jesus who was to die, the Father resurrected him and the glorified Christ then ascended back to the Father in heaven. ***This brings us to Hebrews 9:27, the return back to heaven, in glory***. Hebrews chapter 1 shows that the Son is no mere angel, and that he "sat down on the right hand of the Majesty on high" (vs. 3) whereas all the angelic sons of God stand around that throne of God, which has the Lamb in its center. The Lamb is Christ Jesus. All heaven's creatures worship him who sits on the throne, and the Lamb - Revelation 5:6 & 8-14.

The myriad angelic sons of God appear in order to **stand** before God's throne in heaven, in Job. The appearing of the Son of God in heaven in Hebrews is for this unique, uncreated One to both **sit** alongside God and to ***simultaneously*** **be in the centre of that throne**, which is surrounded by the seven-fold Spirit of God (simultaneously depicted as the seven eyes of the glorified Christ on that throne). All the sons of God worship that symbolically triune depiction of the Almighty, thus fulfilling **Hebrews 1:6, where all the angelic sons are commanded to worship the Son.**

Comment: The Lamb was killed and raised from the dead. God is immortal. Begotten and uncreated are contradictory.

Comment: @AlexBalilo A father _begets_ His only begotten. God _creates_ many sons - to bring them to glory. Divine begetting is within Deity. Creation is another activity altogether. There is no contradiction at all.

Comment: @Alex Balilo You are moving into a different question to the one you asked. My answer deals with the difference between angels and Jesus Christ appearing before God in heaven. You clearly interpret 'the Lamb' in a way that precludes you believing him to be in the center of God's throne, uniquely sharing it. You might best ask a fresh question about 'begotten' and 'uncreated' being contradictory (in your view).

Comment: @Anne did your 'Creator Son of God' become flesh? You have quoted verses that speak nothing of what you assert. Either quote them for what they DO say or please don't quote them at all. The logos 'made everything that was made'. There is no mention of son creating or being THE Creator in John.

Comment: @Anne. You mentioned the lamb in your answer and I responded to it. The question is not about Jesus is "their Creator' yet that is what you stated on some part of your answer. When words are given meanings that they did not have before, is it wrong to ask and seek clarification? If Jesus is" their Creator" who is the God that he appeared to and what verse substantiate that?

Comment: @steveowen   It's a pity that a good Q about Jesus appearing before God seems to trigger comments that attack the Trinity doctrine. Even those who disagree with it can still stick to the Q, and those who disagree with my answer can down-vote it and say why. But I will not enter into debate about the Trinity doctrine here. No further comments from me.

Comment: @anne I'm not attacking anything. I'm calling to account that you have misspoken and not quoted according to the text, but according to something else. Why write it at all if you have no 'biblical' support? This is BH after all - we should stick to the facts.

Comment: +1.  I think this is a useful answer to the question.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The two primary differences between Satan and Jesus Christ are purpose and authority.

**Purpose**
"Satan" is a transliteration of the Hebrew [שָׂטָן](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h7854/kjv/wlc/0-1/), which means to withstand or adversary. However, it is not "satan" who appears before YHVH, it is **הַ**שָּׂטָ֖ן, **ha**satan, **the** adversary. From the dialog the specific form of adversarial action is to accuse. He accuses Job, and he accuses YHVH of being wrong about Job. [The narrative also implies an accusation YHVH has unfairly protected Job from ha-satan's earlier attacks.]

> <sup>8</sup> Then the LORD said to Satan, “Have you considered My servant Job, that there is none like him on the earth, a blameless and upright man, one who fears God and shuns evil?” <sup>9</sup> So Satan answered the LORD and said, “Does Job fear God for nothing? (Job 1 NKJV)

On the other hand, Jesus Christ is the believer's advocate with the Father:

> My little children, these things I write to you, so that you may not sin. And if anyone sins, we have an Advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous. (1 John 2:1)

**Authority**
It is clear from the events in Job, that ha-satan has the ability to inflict harm and even kill Job. However, he lacks authority to use his power as he would like:

> And the LORD said to Satan, “Behold, all that he has *is* in your power; only do not lay a hand on his *person*.” (Job 1:8)

> And the LORD said to Satan, “Behold, he *is* in your hand, but spare his life.” (Job 2:6)

On the other hand, all authority is in hands of Jesus Christ:

> And Jesus came and spoke to them, saying, “All authority has been given to Me in heaven and on earth. (Matthew 28:19)

**Conclusion**
If the event were to take place today, the adversary would appear before Jesus Christ, who has all authority. Moreover, the New Testament in a sense "renames" ha-satan:

> Then I heard a loud voice saying in heaven, “Now salvation, and strength, and the kingdom of our God, and the power of His Christ have come, for the accuser of our brethren, who accused them before our God day and night, has been cast down. (Revelation 12:10)

Jesus Christ defeated the adversary. Nevertheless, the defeated one continued to accuse the children of God and so is identified as ὁ κατήγωρ τῶν ἀδελφῶν ἡμῶν, the accuser of the brothers of us, or simply, ὁ κατηγορῶν, the [one] accusing.

Comment: What do those last two Jewish phrases translate as (or how do I look them up?)  Also, how do you know these are the only differences? It is my understanding that Satan used to have pipes in his body. But I don't know if they were damaged when he "fell like lightning" from Heaven. Their hearts have to be different, too.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I added the English. Purpose and authority are the two main differences and I limited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

As you are trying to judge a verse in the Hebrew Bible (Job 1:6) you will have to play with the Jewish law in the explanation of the Bible, as the Jews were to ones who wrote the Hebrew bible (OT).
Please note that the "new" testament was written in the City of Nicaea in the year 360 CE by the "Church-fathers" in the Greek language (never did a Hebrew nor an Aramaic version of the NT exist). This very fact, that is being ignored by all Christians, already points out that the NT is inherently wrong and could not have been delivered by the disciples,  who all happened to speak Hebrew and not Greek. So trying to compare the Hebrew to a Greek text of which never a Hebrew version existed is from the onset rather useless.

But anyway, I will give it a go:
The way to explain a verse and more precise now word "Bne El-ohim", is to have a look where the first is time this very word appears in the Hebrew Bible. This is the book of Genesis/Bereshith 6:1 (and yes: it is not by coincidence that this swap of cyphers happened: 1:6 to 6:1, as that verse will give you the answer).
The explanation that is been given for the word Bne Ha-El-ohim is elevated people: Nobility or the Judges. This word is also Used for G'd Himself, as the first and main meaning of the Hebrew word "Elohim" is Judge or power.
For a good perspective: in Jewish mysticism Elohim is not of the throne of Mercy but of the throne of strict Judgment with the use of the forces of nature. The very reason that you will find the word Elohim time after time in the story of the creation as G'd (the name written as the Tetragrammon which is connected to the Throne of Mercy) hid Himself solely to use the forces of nature to create this world.

The name Satan or HaSatan is practically the same. in Hebrew the Ha (ה) is a preposition with the meaning "the".
The first time the word Satan has been found in the Torah (Hebrew Bible) is the book of Numbers in the story of Bileam.
The Bible emphasizes that he is an angel, sent personally by G'd. He is not a fallen angel, not lucifer (pure pagan greek mythology although a latin word, based on a mistranslated verse of Isiah 14), but a loyal servant to G'd who G'd uses to test people (to לשטן), to oppose/make life harder to test human's loyalty to G'd or their firmness in their wickedness.
Based on the results of these exams, G'd determines at the end (of that person's life) what his/her reward and/or punishment will be.

Not sure why people are trying to find other non-biblical (NT and Greek mythology) and non-Jewish sources to search for answers while just knowing Hebrew, Jewish exegesis and Jewish tradition could solve questions like these in a few minutes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The New Testament was not written in Nicea in the year 360 - that's absurd because we have lots of quotes from it in the preceding centuries!

Comment: Could you cite your source for your claim, "the "new" testament was written in the City of Nicaea in the year 360 CE by the Church-fathers"? All the N.T. documents were written in koine Greek in the 1st century CE, the last one being Revelation, by the apostle John, circa 95 CE. They were all being copied and circulated amongst Christian congregations by the end of the 1st century, Greek being the language of Empire. Most of the NT was written by the Jewish scholar Paul, a linguist, before his death 68 CE, but the Q is not about language or Satan. It's comparing Jesus with angels (plural).

Comment: @B.de Vries. Please do not be discouraged by the negative votes to your answer. I am interested to know the Hebrew and Jewish interpretation of everything that is taught in the bible as Jesus is a Jew. Please know that you may enlighten some with your answer and may also face opposition.